# Probability Conditioned on Inequality

Tags: probability, inequality, conditional-probability

I have been considering the question of probabilities conditioned on inequalities. My intuition says that I should end up with a double integral, but I'm worried I've missed something in my solution.

Notation: $F_X(x)=\mathbb{P}(X\le x)$ denotes the CDF of RV X and p(x) the corresponding pdf.

I know the joint distribution $\mathbb{P}(X\le \alpha, Y\le \alpha)=\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}p(x,y) \;dy\;dx$

Condsider $\mathbb{P}(X\le \alpha|Y\le \alpha)$ where X and Y are RV's, for some constant $\alpha>0$.
\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{P}(X\le \alpha|Y\le \alpha) &=& \int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}p(x|Y\le \alpha) \; dx \\
&=& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}p(x,y|Y\le \alpha) \; dx \; dy \;(*)\\
&=& \int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}p(x,y) \;dx \;dy \\
&=& \int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}p(x,y) \;dx \;dy \\
\end{eqnarray}
This has turned into the joint distribution. I think there is something wrong with step (*) but I can't seem to figure out what. Can anyone help me?

I could apply Bayes to $p(x|Y\le \alpha)$ but I can't find a way to make the inequality into something that doesn't involve an inequality.